# How to hide the code while installing an ASP.NET application using an installer?

Tags: c#

I want to install a web application using an installer file (exe or msi). When I install it, all the code in the code behind files is visible. Is there a way to hide the code when it is installed?

Comment: any reason you can't create installer without sources?

Comment: What installer are you using that compiles the code when installing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to precompile the application before packaging it in the installer.

See this link for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228015.aspx

The easiest way of doing it is to use `Publish` option from Visual Studio.